# Why isn't my list.extend() working?

Tags: python, list

The below gives me `None` when I print `VIDEO_COLUMNS`.  What am I missing when extending this list of tuples?

```
DEFAULT_COLUMNS = [
    ('$ios_ifa', 'ios_id'),
    ('Groups', 'groups'),
    ('Lifetime Number of Sessions', 'lifetime_sessions'),
    ('Days Since Last Visit', 'days_since'),
    ('time', 'time'),
    ('Product ID', 'product_id'),
]

VIDEO_COLUMNS = list(DEFAULT_COLUMNS).extend([
    ('Time Watched', 'time_watched'),
    ('Video Length', 'video_length')
])

print VIDEO_COLUMNS
```

Comment: Because `list.extend` is IN-PLACE, which means that it returns `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `VIDEO_COLUMNS = list(DEFAULT_COLUMNS).extend(...)`

The return value of `extend` is `None` and you are assigning that to `VIDEO_COLUMNS`.

You are *not* assigning your "clone" of `DEFAULT_COLUMNS` to `VIDEO_COLUMNS`.

Make sure you grab a reference to your new `list` object first, and then extend it.

```
VIDEO_COLUMNS = list(DEFAULT_COLUMNS)

VIDEO_COLUMNS.extend([
    ('Time Watched', 'time_watched'),
    ('Video Length', 'video_length')
])

print VIDEO_COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 1):

You make a list! Great! Now you perform a method on it that returns nothing. Great! Let's see what happened:

```
Make a list, return the list.
Perform an immediate method on the list.
Extend the list, (Extending does not return anything)
Now that everything is done, return the final result, which is None.
```

So, save it and do it in steps:

```
VIDEO_COLUMNS = list(DEFAULT_COLUMNS)
VIDEO_COLUMNS.extend([
('Time Watched', 'time_watched'),
('Video Length', 'video_length')])
```